# Character encoding issues - Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, character-encoding

I made a simple query to a remote database. The table where I make query has all fields with VARCHAR2. However, some fields returns "?" in characters like º, £. I checked enconding and get:

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET: AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET:AL16UTF16
```

Checking my /etc/default/locale file. These are the results:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pt_BR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pt_BR.UTF-8"
```

The enconding from both edges are UTF-8. Is there another configuration that I missing?

Comment: I assume this has nothing to do with PL/SQL (Oracle's procedural programming language, used for functions and procedures), and instead it is for plain SQL? If so, please edit the title and the tags at the bottom of your post.

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'some fields return "?" in characters like ...' I assume that is shown on your screen, right? You don't know what is REALLY returned, you only know what's on your screen.

To see what is REALLY returned, you could do something like

```
select dump('£500') from dual;

DUMP('£500')             
--------------------------
Typ=96 Len=4: 163,53,48,48
```

**EDIT**: As discussed in the comments below, if you type EXACTLY that command at your terminal and you do, in fact, have a display problem, you will see garbage on the way in. Rather, to see what is stored in the database, you must refer to an actual table, and a column that has those string values in it. For example if the column name is COL1 in the table TBL, and there is also an ID column and for ID = 1000 you have a COL1 value with the pound sign in it, run

```
select dump(COL1) from TBL where ID = 1000;
```

Obviously, there are no issues with the INPUT since the input no longer has a pound sign in it (like my first example did). But on the way out, the DUMP may show the proper character is there - however your display is not able to show it correctly.

**END EDIT**

If you see the code 163 in the DUMP, that means the pound sign is stored correctly in the database, and the issue is just how it is displayed on your screen. In that case, you may have an issue with your NLS_LANG setting. There is excellent information here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html

If you find that you have to work with different character sets often, you may benefit from reading this article carefully. It will show you how to find out what your current character set is, how to change it, and why the "obvious" things one would look at are in fact not very helpful. The issue is not too complicated, but not trivial either.

Comment: Running this SQL statement returns: 

DUMP('??500')
----------------------------------------------
Typ=96 Len=9: 239,191,189,239,191,189,53,48,48

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.... You should use the DUMP function on an existing column in one of your tables (FROM <table_name> WHERE <some condition so only a few rows are returned, making sure they are rows that contain the special characters with the problem>). I'll edit the answer to clarify. What happened when you tried exactly as I posted is that your INPUT is affected by the exact same issue as the OUTPUT. But what is stored in the DB should not be affected.